# How to stop looping a sound in android?

Tags: java, android

I need to play a sound 1 time, but he is looping infinity.

I don't understand why is this happening.

If i use a built sound "`mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.test);`" - sound is not looping.

If i use a external sound "mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse(audio.getPath()));" - sound is looping.

This my code

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse(audio.getaPath()));
mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);

mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
{
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
    {

        mp.start();
    }
});
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
{
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        finish();
    }
});
```

Can anybody help me? Thx

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in a button:

```
    Intent intent_upload = new Intent();
    intent_upload.setType("audio/*");
    intent_upload.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent_upload, 222);
```

result:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case 222:
            if (requestCode == 222) {

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    //the selected audio.
                    Uri uri = data.getData();

                    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);
                    mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);

                    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mp -> mp.start());
                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mp -> finish());

                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
    }
}
```

I tried it and it's works fine maybe you missed something in your activity?

Comment: did not help :(

Comment: could you post your activity codes where you're using `MediaPlayer`

Answer (score 0):

you should use `mp.pause()` instead of `finish()`

```
       mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, 
          Uri.parse(audio.getaPath()));
         mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);

         mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
           {
     public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
        {

    mp.start();
     }
   });
       mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
   {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
     {
            mp.pause();
               }
                });
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
 private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
public void stop() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
}
public void play(Context context, String name) {
    stop();

    //mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, rid);
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ context.getPackageName()+"/your_file/"+name+".mp3"));
    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            stop();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You shouldn't be creating and destroying media player objects.  They're expensive to create, and should be reused instead.